# How to setup Broadlink Node Red

Tags: node-red

Does anybody know how to setup the broadlink node on red node? I can’t seem to get it do anything. I’m not sure what the mapping section is on the setup menu.  I’ve recently purchased a RM3 broadlink, and a light switch, I’ve got them to work via the iOS app, but would like to be able to get via the node red package on my raspberry Pi 3. I’ve installed the broadlink devices node but can’t find anywhere info on how to use them.

Comment: You need to share a lot more information for anybody to be able to help. A link to the node you are using would be a good start, along with editing the question to include what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to control Broadlink wifi switch with node-red-contrib-broadlink module. First use "Discover" node to find out your wifi switch MAC and IP. Just inject something in to trigger discovery and attach some debug node to collect information.

You will get:

```
[{"mac":"b4430dfb736b","ip":"192.168.1.1","type":"SPMini2"}]
```

The MAC is OK, but the IP is wrong and you must find IP ow wifi switch from your router DHCP.

Then you pick a SP2 node and enter MAC and IP in the "Device" configuration.
You can getState ot setState to the device from SP2 node.

I tried also the A1 node, but it returns some nonsense temperature/humidity information:

```
{"temperature":0,"humidity":279.5,"light":"Normal","air_quality":"Perfect","noise":"Silent"}
```